# How to re-include excluded folder in SSDT-BI / Visual Studio 2013 database project?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt

I've selected "Excluded from project" on a folder with tables (database was imported first into project). Now I would like to re-include this folder into the project. In the "Add Existing Item" option it's not possible. Only files can be added like that. Do you know how to do that ? Is it possible or should I re-create the folder and add the files there again manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually fairly easy to do. Do *not* re-create the folder.

With Visual Studio open and the solution loaded, do the following:

1. View the Solution Explorer (shows on the right side).
2. Select either the project or any of the folders or items within the project.
3. In the top button bar within Solution Explorer, click on the <kbd>**>>**</kbd> button on the far right. Three or four new buttons should appear below your cursor (depending on what type of item you had selected).
4. The far left button in the new set that appeared when you clicked the <kbd>**>>**</kbd> is for <kbd>Show All Files</kbd>. Click that. You should now see folders and files, etc that are dotted outline icons instead of solid shapes.
5. Right click on the folder that was previously excluded from the project.
6. Select <kbd>Include In Project</kbd>.
7. In the top button bar within Solution Explorer, click on the <kbd>**>>**</kbd> button on the far right. Three or four new buttons should appear below your cursor (depending on what type of item you had selected).
8. The far left button in the new set that appeared when you clicked the <kbd>**>>**</kbd> should already be selected. Click that to re-hide all of the folders and files, etc with the dotted outline icons.